# GET Request with JS

Tags: javascript, python, flask, get, httprequest

i need to send a GET request from my JavaScript function to my python flask app. However, i tried to type the URL with the parameters manually and it worked. But i can't send the same request in a JS function. Response type is HTML.

This is how the URL should look like:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/books?rank=2&topic=Self improvement

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
function sendRequest() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/books', {
        rank: rank,
        topic: topic
    });

    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

What the URL looked like with this try:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/books

Please help!

Comment: Consider not using `XMLHttpRequest` and use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch) instead?

Comment: [open's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) third argument isn't a query string.

You should really use modern [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `'/books?' + new URLSearchParams({ rank, title })` will also do it.

Comment: @Christopher - ***Thank you!*** When I was writing that I thought "I'm sure there's an easier and less error-prone way to do this." but it wasn't coming to me and it was driving me a bit batty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass the parameters in a POST body (the third argument to `open`). That won't work for a GET, they have to be in the URL.

The easiest and least error-prone way is to use `URLSearchParams` *(thank you [Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10304804/christopher) for pointing that out when I forgot!)*:

```
const url = "/books?" + new URLSearchParams({rank, title});
```

Live Example:

```js
const rank = 42;
const title = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
const url = "/books?" + new URLSearchParams({rank, title});
console.log(url);
```

These days, you'd usually use the more modern `fetch` rather than `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function sendRequest() {
    const url = "/books?" + new URLSearchParams({rank, title});
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.text(); // Or `.json()` or one of the others
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        });
}
```

But if you prefer to use `XMLHttpRequest`, put the parameters in the URL (and handle errors):

```
function sendRequest() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "/books?" + new URLSearchParams({rank, title});
    xhr.open("GET", url);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        // ...handle/report error...
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

(You can also use string concatenation and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to build the URL, but it's more work and more error-prone. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I made a code with fetch() based on the comments above, let me know if you get any errors. Hope this helps, XMLHttpRequest() is not used much due to its complexity.

```
 async function sendRequest(){
    const url = 'your URL';
     await fetch(url,{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        
        }
      }).then(response=>{
        if(response.status !=200) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP ERROR:${response.status}`);
        } 
        return response.text()
        }

    ).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      // convert to html
  
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: This question really doesn't need any answers posted, it's just the OP getting the arguments to a common function wrong. Separately, it's difficult to understand answers when you change multiple things unrelated to the thing that needs changing (why change the function name? do you know it's okay to make it `async`? Why the full URL instead a relative one?).

Comment: The above is also slightly incorrect in two ways: 1. You're not checking for HTTP errors. 2. Your code says you're sending JSON **to** the server. But you aren't. You aren't sending any request body at all, because the request is a GET, not a POST or PUT. The `Content-Type` in a header in a request says what the request body is; the response body's type is defined by the **response** `Content-Type` header. (You could use `Accept` to say that a JSON response is okay.)

Comment: Hi, after changing "title" to "topic" in your code, i was able to read the params with the python code. But i still get this error after that: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON . I think this is because the response type is expected to be HTML

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I made some changes I put Accept, some questions above were to meet the demands of the user with their problem.

```

```